# How to take user input from one page and display it in a table on another page in HTML

Tags: javascript, c#, html

There's lots of videos of how to do it if the table and the user input fields are on the same page, but I'm really struggling to get the data to transfer across pages. [The First page looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4C9l.png). That is where the user is supposed to enter their information. [After they hit submit its goes to this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZ6wp.png) where it has to take their name and display it with a thank you. Finally [you have the third page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFBxG.png) here it shows all of the user entered info from the first page in a table. I've got all the pages up and working just fine, I just need to figure out how to get the data from the first page to display on the second and third pages. I know the code isn't pretty, just need it working before I make it look better.

Here is the code for the first page which takes the user input.

```html
@page
@model RSVPModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "RSVP";
}
<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content=" width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>RSVP</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type=" text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>

<body>
        <div id=" container">
            <div class=" input">Name: <input id="name" type="text" /></div>
            <div class=" input">Age: <input id="age" type="number" /></div>
            <div class=" input">Arrival Time: <input id="arrtime" type="time" /></div>
            <label for="parking">Request Parking?</label>
            <select name="parking" id="parking"> 
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="yes">yes</option>
                <option value="no">no</option>
            </select>

            <form action="Submitted">
                <button id="entry">Submit RSVP</button>
            </form>

        </div>
    

    <script>
        var row = 1;

        var entry = document.getElementById('entry');
        entry.addEventListener("click", displayDetails);

        function displayDetails() {
            var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
            var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
            var arrtime = document.getElementById("arrtime").value;
            var parking = document.getElementById("parking").value;

            if (!name || !age || !arrtime || !parking) {
                alert("Please fill all fields before proceeding");
                return;
            }

            var display = document.getElementById("display");

            var newRow = display.insertRow(row);

            var cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
            var cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
            var cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2);
            var cell4 = newRow.insertCell(3);

            cell1.innerHTML = name;
            cell2.innerHTML = age;
            cell3.innerHTML = arrtime;
            cell4.innerHTML = parking;

            row++;
        }
    </script>
</body>    
</html>
```

Here is the code to the second page (confirmation page)

```html
@page
@model SubmittedModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "RSVP Submitted";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Thank you for your RSVP!</h1>
    <p>It's great that you're coming. The drinks are already in the fridge!</p>
    <p>Click <a href="GuestList">here</a> to see who is coming.</p>
</div>
```

And finally the code to the guest list or page with the table

```html
@page
@model PrivacyModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Here is a list of people attending the party";
}
<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

<table id="display">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Arrival Time</th>
        <th>Request Parking</th>
    </tr>
</table>
<script src="Script.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think easiest way is to use localStorage of JS or get query params.